# phpStorm remote debugging selecting sending wrong ip address during remote debug

Tags: php, remote-debugging, phpstorm

does anyone know how to set the interface ip that phpstorm sends for remote debug? I am debugging a remote site and it keeps sending a wrong interface (i have several )

when i start the debug it starts the browser :

http://192.168.0.251/?start_debug=1&send_sess_end=1&debug_start_session=1&debug_session_id=19689&debug_port=10137&debug_host=169.254.98.211%2C127.0.0.1&debug_stop=1

the ip address 169.254.98.211 should be 192.168.0.135
and if i change it manually, it works !

so where do i set this??

Khan

Comment: How do you start debugging? Provide a screenshot of the configuration in PhpStorm. Do you use xdebug? What xdebug settings are in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: i am using zend debugger

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/79611645@N05/6981646098/
screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **PHP Web Application** Debug configuration, the value of the `debug_host` cannot be defined by the user, it's hardcoded:

```
  public static String getDebugHost() {
    try {
      final InetAddress localHost = Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
      return localHost.getHostAddress() + ",127.0.0.1";
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      return "127.0.0.1";
    }
  }
```

A workaround would be to use [**Zero-configuration Debugging**](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/) where you can define the host IP address in the [bookmarklet generator](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/). Don't get confused by the xdebug, it's almost the same for Zend Debugger.